# $_FILES Undefined index: file

Tags: upload

My `$_Files` isn't working and i did everything i read from all people remarks. Maybe someone can help me

```
<div class="form-check">
    Select File :
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
save
```

I put this line(and many more)

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
```

and I'm getting an error :"Notice: Undefined index: file"

Someone suggested to put this 2 lines before. it help only for "file" but it didn't know all the other properties like: size, tmp ....

```
$_FILES['file'] = array(); 
$_FILES['file']['name'] = $_POST['file'];
```

and i checked that in my php.ini the upload in on.

I would really love to get help

Comment: Welcole to stackoverflow, please ask question with some snippets of your code, for more visit : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Aggestor thank you for the remark, I changed it